# Image view in grid view is scrolled partially when we do scroll on grid view

Tags: android

I have gridview with two columns. Users can scroll vertically to see gridview items.

The problem is when the user has finished scrolling, the first row is not completely visible. I want to set the top of first visible row to top of gridview so first row is completely visible.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: post code what you have tried so far, so that its easy to point out

Comment: means data in first row should be visible after scrolling down???

Comment: You meant first row or row with headings?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this. I tried with ListView in My Project

```
        mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
            private int currentVisibleItemCount;
            private int currentScrollState;

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            }

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                this.isScrollCompleted();
             }

            private void isScrollCompleted() {
                if (mGridView.getLastVisiblePosition() == mGridView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                        && mGridView.getChildAt(mGridView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= mGridView.getHeight()) {
                    if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                           mGridView.smoothScrollToPosition(-1);
                      }
                    }
                  }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried your solution.it is not working.Actually i have 10 rows with images and 2 columns. when we doing scrolling vertically on grid view. Images of row out of 10 is not completely visible. Please find my code in below.